# Strings go out of tune (flat) when I bend them, then back to normal when I use the vibrato bar

Tags: electric-guitar, tuning

I have an American Standard strat, and I last changed all the strings 3 months ago. As of the last 2 weeks, I've noticed that my G string gets out of tune when I bend it: it goes roughly a quarter tone flat. When I use the vibrato bar I hear a faint clicking noise and then the string goes back into tune.

Now it's starting to happen with the B string too.

I tried completely releasing the tension on the strings and bringing it back in tune again, but the problem persists. Next thing I will try is to restring my guitar and see if it fixes it.

Is that something you've seen before? Does it have an easy fix?

Comment: Bit of lube needed on any surfaces moving against each other should do it. Graphite? Were it the wound strings there could be binding in the nut.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I think they describe the opposite problem to mine, but I will try the graphite in the nut

Comment: It's two sides of the same issue, bending pulls through the nut, whammy lets it slip back again.

Comment: Be very surprised if plain strings jam anywhere.

Comment: My G string is flat not wound, indeed. So is my B string for the record.